# The user that do Changed Data Capture (CDC) must be DBA?

Tags: sql-server

The user that do Changed Data Capture (CDC) must be DBA? if no, what the privilege that grant to the user that do CDC, please?

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: if the user want to do Changed Data Capture (CDC), the user must be DBA?

Comment: what does it mean "to do Changed Data Capture (CDC)"? CDC works without users. SQL server automatically detects changes and writes them to CDC tables

Comment: Do you mean setting up CDC with "do"? Please try to be clear with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To control CDC you have to be `sysadmin` or `db_owner`. See more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369.aspx